# LINQ to returns count even the list is empty

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have this block of code inside another LINQ statement.

```
 VideoLinks = (from video in m.VideoLinks.DefaultIfEmpty(new VideoGallery())
                                              orderby video.CreatedDate
                                              select new VideoGallery()
                                              {
                                                  Source = video.Source,
                                                  Type = video.Type,
                                                  Links = video.Links,
                                                  Title = video.Title
                                              }).ToList()
```

unfortunately if dont use DefaultIfEmpty its through me an exception. If I use DefaultIfEmpty i give count as 1 for videolinks even if m.VideoLinks is null.

So now how can avoid getting count 1 if m.VideoLinks is null

Comment: What is the exception you are receiving?

Comment: I dont understand the reason for the downvote. My question is not about exception or how to solve the exception it is about the count and how to make it zero. Exception is object reference not set to instance of an object

Comment: I didn't vote it down, Praneeth. Not sure of the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like you are using linq-to-objects, so you should add a `where video != null`

```
VideoLinks = (from video in m.VideoLinks
              where video != null
              orderby video.CreatedDate
              select new VideoGallery()
              {
                Source = video.Source,
                Type = video.Type,
                Links = video.Links,
                Title = video.Title
              }).ToList()
```

Comment: Perfect..never thought about where condition.

Answer (score 6):

DefaultIfEmpty is going to give you a default value.  It counts as an item when you call ToList() on it...thus your count is 1.

Comment: My question is how to avoid it?

Comment: Don't use DefaultIfEmpty, that's how.

Comment: You changed your question after I answered it?  Thats not cool.

Comment: Hehe, no problem.  Normally if you need a new question you should rephrase it to only contain what you need to know, but in this case it would be hard to rephrase since you wanted it left in context.  I guess there wasnt a clean way for you to make it a new question.

Answer (score 1):

wllmsaccnt is correct - your problem is the "DefaultIfEmpty" portion of your statement. By definition, you are requesting that there be at least one item in the collection, according to the definition of this method:

> Returns the elements of the specified sequence or the specified value
>   in a singleton collection if the sequence is empty

I think the important question here is what exception are you receiving when you don't use DefaultIfEmpty? If you tell us that, perhaps we can help you avoid it...